# How can I call an ArrayAdapter from another activity to delete item from ArrayAdapter with strings.xml array?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

**Summary of problem:**   The adapter and spinner are all in the Spinner Activity.  Once user picks a name, it sends them to the Main Activity.  I want to call an ArrayAdapter from another activity and delete an item from that list but can't seem to figure out how to do so.  I use an ArrayAdapter and attach a list to it from `strings.xml` and using `string-array name="horizon_names"`

[Call custom ArrayAdapter method from another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595051/call-custom-arrayadapter-method-from-another-activity) doesn't answer my problem.

**What I have tried:** I have tried making `ArrayAdapter` public and trying to call it in the other activity but nothing comes up.

**Spinner Selection Activity:**

```
public class SpinnerSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner spinner;
TextView tvPackage;
String stringSelectionPackage;
Button bSaveSelection;
Context context;
public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_selection);
    context = this;

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // Name Selection (1-24)
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    tvPackage= findViewById(R.id.tvPackage);
    //Array Adapter for creating list
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.names, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    //Save Selection Button Code
    bSaveSelection = findViewById(R.id.bSaveSelection);
    bSaveSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
MainActivity.class);
            stringSelectionPackage= 
tvPackage.getText().toString();
            myIntent.putExtra("name", stringSelectionPackage);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, 
long l) {
    //Put user selection into String text
    String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    //Store text in tvPackage to send it to MainActivity and 
place in @id/textViewName TextView
    tvPackage.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}


}
```

**Main Activity:**

```
   Within onCreate

 //GETTING NAME FROM SPINNER SELECTION 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("name");
        textViewName.setText(value);
        **THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DELETE ITEM FROM LIST**
        adapter.remove(value);


    }
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="names">
        <item>Name 01</item>
        <item>Name 02</item>
        <item>Name 03</item>
        <item>Name 04</item>
        <item>Name 05</item>
    </string-array>
```

**Expected and actual results** I expect to be able to call the ArrayAdapter from the other activity, and delete the item that the user picked in the main activity but I am not able to call the ArrayAdapter in the MainActivity.

Comment: `Within onCreate` - I think here lays your problem. `onCreate` is called only when `Activity` needs to be created. If you start second `Activity` the first one will go in `onPause` after you `finish()` with your second `Activity` first `Activity` will be resumed by calling `onResume` so I would move that code here instead of `onCreate`

Comment: I'll clarify; the name selection screen shows up first and after a user selects a name they are sent to the main activity where I want to delete the name from the list the user selected.

Comment: Your `adapter` is inside `SpinnerSelection` not in `MainActivity` correct?

Comment: Correct.  The adapter and spinner are all in the Spinner Activity.  Once user picks a name, it sends them to the Main Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task which you want to acomplish requires different approach.

Summary of problem:

> Your `adapter` is inside `SpinnerSelection` which is `finished`
>   immediately after user selects value from `Spinner` that means that
>   every next time when `SpinnerSelection` is started you will have same values again in `Spinner` because
>   `Spinner` is `re-created` inside `onCreate` and populated with values from `string-array`. Hardcoded resource files are constant can not be removed on runtime.

Solution:

You need to store values for `Adapter` somewhere else, for example in `SQLite` or `SharedPreferences` (if it is small amount of data) not in `string-array`. That will allow you to delete the values from place where you have saved them and once value is deleted from there, `Spinner` will not have it when `SpinnerSelection` is launched.

Comment: This sounds promising.  Do you have an example code of how to use SharedPreferences to display the list in the spinner?

Comment: That is the way if you want to delete the value regardless of app state unless user `re-install` the app. If you want that value is removed in that case as well consider using some online database like `Firebase`. 
Common way to do that is to convert `List` of values in `JSON` and than save that `JSON` as a `String` for example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107647/how-to-save-listobject-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: What if I create a List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Name 01"); ?  

When i try to populate the list into the adapter like this ``adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, deviceNameList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);`` I get an error "Wrong 2nd Arg type.  Required (Int)"

Comment: Figured it out.  Changed the adapter to this ``adapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);``  and just use adaper.remove() to remove from the list.  Good leads.

Comment: Yes because `Spinner` accepts primitive `array` not `generic List` you need to convert `List` to `array`. You can remove the value in runtime from the `List` but once app starts again you will have same values in `Spinner` so saving somewhere else which will keep the values regardless of app state is necessary in your case.